# TypeError: Cannot read property 'endpoint_link_1' of undefined when trying to display API data in CardView, NativeScript-Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

NativeScript-Vue and JavaScript beginner here. Well, I'm not versed in heavy Javascript coding in general. I'm having some trouble displaying the data received from an API in CardViews. This is the code I have tried:

```
<template>
<Page >
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout padding="5" for="item in cardList">
        <CardView ripple="true" elevation="10" padding="5" margin="15" height="150">
            <StackLayout>
            <Image :src="'http://URL' + item.endpoint_link_1" stretch="aspectFit" height="120"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </CardView>

        <CardView ripple="true" elevation="10" padding="5" margin="15" height="150">
            <StackLayout>
            <VideoPlayer :src="'http://URL' + item.endpoint_link_2"  controls="true" stretch="aspectFill" autoplay="false" height="120"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </CardView>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
</Page>
</template>


<script>
import * as http from "http";

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            cardList: []
        };
    },

    mounted() {
        http.getJSON("http://URL").then(result => {
                this.cardList = result.results;
                console.log(result); #This shows the results in the log so I know it works.
                console.log(cardList); #doesn't show anything in log
            }, error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };
</script>
```

My JSON data is nested like this:

```
[
    {
        "endpoint_link_1": "/default/files/image.jpg",
        "endpoint_link_2": ""
    },
    {
        "endpoint_link_1": "",
        "endpoint_link_2": "/default/files/video.mp4"
    }
]
```

The error I get when I try this is: `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'endpoint_link_1' of undefined"`. I suspect that the list `cardList` isn't being populated or I have the `for="item in cardList"` in the wrong place. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: ain't you suppose to use `v-for`?

Answer (score 0):

use `v-for` instead of `for` and in the script :
`console.log(this.cardList);`  will show you data